# Backbone Fetch success callback not executing when fetch response is an empty array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have `Person` model and I am retrieving a person info inside a view. The `success` callback `FetchSuccess` executes when the response has an object. But when response is empty, the callback is not called. Any Guess?

```
Models.Basic = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});

Models.PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return '/person/' + this.data.id;
    }
});

Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Templates['template'],

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.id = options.id;
        _.bindAll(this, 'FetchSuccess');

        this.personModel = new Models.PersonModel();
        this.model = new Models.Basic();
        this.fetchData();
        return this;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    fetchData: function() {
        this.personModel.data = {
            id: this.id
        };
        this.personModel.fetch({
            context: this,
            success: this.FetchSuccess
        });
    },

    FetchSuccess: function() {
        this.model.set({
            name: this.personModel.get('name');
        });
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: `Models.collectionModel` why you are extending backbone model instead of collection

Comment: hey i updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.personModel = new Models.PersonModel();
```

This is a Backbone Model, not a collection.

```
this.personModel.fetch({
    reset: true, // this doesn't exist on model
    success: this.FetchSuccess
});
```

You can't fetch a model without an `id`. Also, the model, when fetching, expects an object to be returned.

If you want to fetch a specific person, give an `id` to the model, then fetch.

```
this.personModel = new Models.PersonModel({ id: "id_here" });
// ...
this.personModel.fetch({
    context: this,
    success: this.FetchSuccess
});
```

Here's the code with the corrections

```
// parse isn't needed if you're not going to parse something
Models.Basic = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Models.PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'person/', // this handles putting the id automatically
});

Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Templates['template'],

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.id = options.id;

        // pass the id here
        this.personModel = new Models.PersonModel({ id: this.id });

        this.model = new Models.Basic();
        this.fetchData();

        // makes no sense in the initialize since it's never called 
        // manually and never used to chain calls.
        // return this; 
    },

    render: function() {
        // render should be idempotent, so emptying before appending
        // is a good pattern.
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this; // this is where chaining could happen
    },

    fetchData: function() {
        // This makes no sense unless you've stripped the part that uses it.
        // this.personModel.data...

        this.personModel.fetch({
            context: this, // pass the context, avoid `_.bindAll`
            success: this.onFetchSuccess,
            error: this.onFetchError
        });
    },

    onFetchSuccess: function() {
        this.model.set({
            name: this.personModel.get('name')
        });
        this.render();
    },
    onFetchError: function() { this.render(); }

});
```

You could catch the error with the `error` callback, or just do nothing and render by default, and re-render on fetch.

You could also listen to the model events (inside the `initialize`):

```
this.listenTo(this.personModel, {
    'sync': this.FetchSuccess,
    'error': this.onFetchError
});
this.personModel.fetch();
```

Comment: This is working perfectly when response of fetch is not empty. But when response is empty, callback did not execute

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri if the response is empty, the fetch has failed by design even if it returns a 200 OK.

Comment: Can you tell me how to handle such case

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri it really depends on what you want, if you want to handle the error, there's the `error` callback.

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri I updated my answer with additional details on handling errors.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I guess if you use .done and .fail callbacks then empty array will also succeed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nikhilmehta you're right, `.done` and `.fail` would be called like the fetch options callbacks. I just favor the options callbacks or events when possible.